# LWC Login Component: Unreachable statement

Tags: apex, community

I'm creating a LWC Login component as outlined here (https://hicglobalsolutions.com/blog/how-to-create-a-custom-login-and-signup-page-using-lwc-for-the-salesforce-community/). When compiling the new controller I get:

- Unreachable statement

How do I resolve this issue:

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static string doLogin(String username, String password){
        try {
            
            String startUrl = System.Label.Community_Url;
            ApexPages.PageReference pageRef = Site.login(username, password, startUrl);

            if(pageRef != null) return pageRef.getUrl();

            throw new CalloutException();

            return null;


        } catch (Exception e) {
            system.debug('e.getMessagelogin+   '+e.getMessage());
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In both your `try` and `catch` blocks, you have an unconditional `throw` statement, followed by a `return` statement.  In both blocks, the `return` statement is unreachable because the `throw` statement exits normal execution of the `doLogin` method.  Try removing both `return` statements.